# mkdir(): No such file or directory - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com um problema no `Laravel`, referente na hora de criar uma pasta no `Windows`, com este método ele cria a pasta no `Linux`, exibe o erro:

> `ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 435:mkdir(): No such file or directory`

Minha função que salva no Linux:

```
public function salvar($objArquivo, $objProjeto, $objDataAtualizacao) 
{
    if (is_object($objProjeto->data_criacao)) 
    {
        $dataAbertura = $objProjeto->data_criacao->format('Y');
    } 
    else 
    {
        try 
        {
            $anoAberturaProjeto = 
                \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', 
                                $objProjeto->data_criacao);
        } 
        catch(\Exception $e) 
        {
            $anoAberturaProjeto = 
                \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', 
                                $objProjeto->data_criacao);
        }
        $dataAbertura = $anoAberturaProjeto->format('Y');
    }
    // 'public/projetos_arquivos/year/codigo_projeto'
    $strCaminho = public_path('projetos_arquivos'). 
                    DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dataAbertura . 
                    DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $objProjeto->codigo; 

    // Nomeia arquivo com codigo do projeto + data passada como argumento
    $strNome = $objProjeto->codigo . "_" . $objDataAtualizacao->format("Y_m_d"); 

    // Cria pasta para o projeto, caso não já exista uma   
    if(!file_exists($strCaminho)) 
    {          
        var_dump($strCaminho);
        $objProjetoDiretorio = File::makeDirectory($strCaminho);
    }

    // Salvando arquivo no servidor
    $objArquivo->move($strCaminho, $strNome . ".pdf"); 
    $strCaminhoArquivo = $strCaminho . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $strNome . ".pdf";

    return($strCaminhoArquivo);
}
```

até coloquei um `var_dump($strCaminho);` e o caminho exibe assim 
`C:\xamp2\htdocs\pmi\public\projetos_arquivos\2018\162`
só que estar exibindo a mensagem.

Comment: Qual é a linha `line 435`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, creio que `File::makeDirectory` seja laravel4 e não o 5, no 5 creio que nem existe esta função (se eu não estiver enganado)

Talvez você esteja tentando criar em uma pasta que não existe, por exemplo, não existe o `2018`, logo não pode criar a pasta `162` no caminho:

```
C:\xamp2\htdocs\pmi\public\projetos_arquivos\2018\162
```

Então se for isto basta você criar de maneira recursiva (o proprio `makeDirectory` faz isto) desta maneira:

```
// Cria pasta para o projeto, caso não já exista uma   
if(!file_exists($strCaminho)) 
{
    $objProjetoDiretorio = File::makeDirectory($strCaminho, 0775, true);
}
```

Para suprimir os erros usaria assim:

```
$objProjetoDiretorio = File::makeDirectory($strCaminho, 0775, true, true);
```

Agora se realmente for o Laravel 5, creio que na verdade esteja usando [`Illuminate\Filesystem::makeDirectory`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c34164f071e30bd70652e780467cc31cb4ea18ad/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L436), o principio é o mesmo do `File`:

```
use Illuminate\Filesystem;

...

// Cria pasta para o projeto, caso não já exista uma
if(!file_exists($strCaminho)) 
{
    $objProjetoDiretorio = Filesystem::makeDirectory($strCaminho, 0775, true);
}
```

Se quiser suprimir os erros:

```
$objProjetoDiretorio = Filesystem::makeDirectory($strCaminho, 0775, true, true);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Guilherme ,muito obrigado mesmo =]  era isso mesmo o exemplo que funcionou foi o exemplo citado no laravel 4 coloquei e conseguiu criar a pasta 2018 e colocar o arquivo pdf dentro dela =] perfeito !!!

Answer (score 1):

Como você está usando um servidor `Linux`, precisa dar permissões, o usuário nativo do `php` que faz a criação de pastas é `www-data`.

Então na pasta por exemplo `projetos_arquivos`, você precisa alterar o dono dela para o usuário `www-data` do `php` para que ele tenha permissão de escrita e modificação.

Faz o seguinte, gera este comando na raiz onde está a pasta fixa que imagino eu ser a `projetos_arquivos`:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data ./projetos_arquivos
```

Isso permite um novo dono, sua pasta onde conterá outras subpastas poderá conter outras criadas dinamicamente agora.

Espero que ajude você!

Comment: meu amigo ..putz desculpa no linux ele cria... é no windows que não cria a pasta ,vou editar putz!!!

Comment: O windows não tem muito essas restrições, talvez você não apontou o diretório corretamente, por isso ele está dizendo que não encontra o local. Veja com calma.